# Clearing vectors and letting one vector equal another

Tags: c++, vector

Right I have two vectors. I want to empty the vector(list) and replace its contents with the contents of the other vector(templist) and clear templist when I've done that. Is this the right code?

```
list.clear();
list = templist;
templist.clear();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what the swap method is for:

```
list.swap(templist); // The contents are swapped
templist.clear(); // Clear the one you don't need anymore
```

Note that this is faster than `list = templist` because the contents are not copied.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: Swap is much better than assignment, because the latter performs an unnecessary copy of the whole vector.

Comment: `list = std::move(templist); templist.clear()` I find easier to read

Comment: that swap worked really well! thanks! One additional question if that's ok. I have list as a global variable. Will this change it for all other functions?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:

```
list = templist;
templist.clear();
```